# How to pass the reCaptcha token in the g-recaptcha-response property

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, email-client

I am using Emailjs to handle my email deliveribility but I have an issue when it comes to recatcha verification.

The HTML form works well without the verification but once I activate the recaptcha in emailjs, I will no more get the notification in my email when the form is filled. Emailjs doc says:

> To add CAPTCHA support:
>
> 1. Create reCaptcha(opens new window) account or login to the existing account.
> 2. Register a new site and add your site domain to the list of domains. If you want to test the template in JSFiddle, please also add
>    jsfiddle.net to the list.
> 3. Follow the "client-side integration" instructions as specified in the reCaptcha dashboard. If you are using the send method, please pass
>    the reCaptcha token in the g-recaptcha-response property.
> 4. Open your template in the EmailJS template editor, go to Settings tab, and check Enable reCAPTCHA V2 verification checkbox.
> 5. Specify the secret key obtained from reCaptcha dashboard.

After the above steps have been completed it won’t be possible to send out an email based on this template without solving a CAPTCHA test first. No additional changes are required – we will automatically send the solved CAPTCHA result along with the send email request."

---

The issue is, I am just a beginner in javascript and I don't seem to understand how to pass the recaptcha token.

Here is my code:

The form

```
<head>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
  
  <!--recaptcha-->
  <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@emailjs/browser@3/dist/email.min.js">
</script>

<!--emailjs-->
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function(){
      emailjs.init("EMAILJS_KEY");
   })();
</script>
</head>
```

```
<div class="form-container">
            <h2>Contact Me</h2>
            <p>Feel free to contact me and I will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
            <form  method="POST" id="shev-form">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name_id" placeholder="Name" required>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email_id" placeholder="Email" required>
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject_id" placeholder="Subject" required>
                <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="5" id="message_id" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY_SITE_KEY"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_id" onclick="sendMail()">
            </form>
            </div>
```

The javascript:

```
function sendMail() {
  var params = {
    name: document.getElementById("name_id").value,
    email: document.getElementById("email_id").value,
    subject: document.getElementById("subject_id").value,
    message: document.getElementById("message_id").value,
    
  };

  const serviceID = "service_ID";
  const templateID = "template_ID";

    emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, params)
    .then(res=>{
        document.getElementById("name_id").value = "";
        document.getElementById("email_id").value = "";
        document.getElementById("subject_id").value = "";
        document.getElementById("message_id").value = "";
        console.log(res);
        alert("Your message sent successfully!!")

    })
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));

}
```

If the recaptcha is not sending a valid response to emailjs, the email will not be submitted.

Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Some small notes for you: [you don't need to say "thanks in advance"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288179/11107541), and ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Take a look at [ask] to get some tips on how to pose a clear, focused question. You can [edit] to make those adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all get the response value:

then pass it to the emailjs.send() as part of params:

```
// Get Google ReCaptcha Score
let captchaToken = grecaptcha.getResponse();
var params = {
  name: document.getElementById("name").value,
  "g-recaptcha-response": captchaToken,
};

emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, params)
```